# Generate model classes from Firebird database

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, eclipselink, firebird

I tried to execute a reverse engineer from Firebird to Java POJO Classes with Eclipse JPA options and with JBoss Tool for Hibernate, without success.

Is says it can't find schemas. And don't give a option to continue.

I tried with NetBeans and with NetBeans I could generate but NetBeans doesn't have the option to generate Lists instead of Sets.

I'm using Firebird 2.5.4, Jaybird 2.2.8 for Java 1.8, Hibernate 4.3.9, Eclipse Mars 4.5 RC3, JBoss Tools nightly.

It seems like some people had the same problem though, as you can see on the links 273360,277493,428978 on Eclipse Bug list https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=firebird&list_id=11981972

Comment: Could you describe in more detail what you did, what you expect and what actually happens (especially if you get any errors)? I am not familiar with JBoss Tools, so a more detailed description would be very helpful.

Comment: If the problem is with the lack of a schema, you might want to try the open office subprotocol (`jdbc:firebirdsql:oo:`) as it includes a dummy schema in the database metadata. Note that not having schemas is allowed by the JDBC specification, so this is a bug in the tool.

Comment: You might also want to try [the Firebird plugin for the Eclipse Data Tools Platform](http://www.lawinegevaar.nl/firebird); it is outdated, but as I understood from others, it still works with recent Eclipse versions.

Comment: thank you so much, the plugin worked perfectly. and the openoffice not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that JBoss tools uses the Eclipse Data Tools Platform. Firebird is not fully supported by default in Eclipse DTP. To add this support you will need to add the Firebird DTP plugin to your eclipse `plugins` folder.

You can download it from the [Firebird DTP plugin GitHub repo](https://github.com/mrotteveel/fbdtp/releases/latest).

The plugin is outdated and hasn't been tested with recent Eclipse versions, but as I understood from others, it still works with recent Eclipse versions.

Disclosure: I developed the Firebird DTP plugin.